# Keyboard does not show up on contenteditable label

Tags: javascript, android, html, label, contenteditable

I have a page displaying some radio button and their label associate. Something like this (http://jsfiddle.net/DLV2F/702/)
On google chrome, there is no problem to edit the text, as the keyboard do not need to be showed up.

But on Android, the keyboard shows up only on input, div with `contenteditable` but not on label.

To be more specific : if you select with an android the div, you can modify it as the keyboard show up, but not in the label :

```
<div contenteditable id="div">DIV: This div will trigger the keyboard</div>
<label contenteditable>LABEL: This label won't</label>
```

Is there any way to make the keyboard (on iOs too if possible) appears?

I tried to make something with the `.select()` on an hidden input. But if an input is not shown (`display: none`) the keyboard doesn't appear either...

---

EDIT : Finally, as there is no event for displaying the keyboard, and because I didn't find any other way, this is how I solve my problem :

I have set a input with an absolute pos and a top:-9999px (because a visibility:hidden or a display:none won't work).

And there :

```
self.html.choicePanel.on('click','__my_label__',function(){
  // We focus our dummy input
  $( '#dummyInput' ).focus();

  // We set the default text as it is in the label
  $( '#dummyInput' ).val( $( "label[for='__THE_ID__']" ).text() );

  // Remove other event on this input that could exist
  $( '#dummyInput' ).off( 'keyup' );

  $( '#dummyInput' ).on( 'keyup', function () {
    // Set cool stuff in our label
    $( "label[for='__THE_ID__']"']" ).text( $( this ).val() );
  });
});
```

And... commit committed.

Comment: When testing your fiddle with chrome I see, that the label has a _for_ attribute. This leads to a focus-loss of the contenteditable. Maybe that is also happening on the android browser?

Comment: @mohlendo Yes, I would like to make a simple div but I have to keep the same appearence that the user will have. 

(In the frontend, the user has just to click on a label to choose it's answer, but in the backend, the administrator change the label with the contenteditable tag, but I keep in label for letting the same comportment that customers would have, it's a customer requirement).

So, I assume there is no other way than making it a "normal" div and trigger the radio input with javascript ? 
Not possible to say to android : Display keyboard please. ?

(thx for you time)

Comment: you can still use the label but you should get rid of the _for_ attribute. Use some javascript to toggle the radio button instead.

Comment: I just tried. The browser detect that it's a editable content (we have the cursor blinking) but the keyboard still play hide-and-seek with me :'(

Comment: Note that you should write your answer in an actual answer and not at the end of your question!